AlmaLinux blocking outgoing connections
I have a new AlmaLinux installation that is blocking outgoing connections to most ports, with the exception of a handful. I notice this mostly because the server runs Exim and no e-mail can be sent on port 25 while it can be received without a problem.
SELinux is not running since sestatus comes back as disabled and I have shut down the firewall completely with sudo systemctl stop firewalld and a telnet portquiz.net 25 will result in a connection timed out while it connects on port 80 regardless of the firwall status. I rule out the hosting since this was working previously on the same server with CentOS, it all started with a fresh install of AlmaLinux.
What other component of the Operating System could be blocking outgoing connections and how to open mail sending ports?

Note that generally blocked SMTP is bad indicator of issues with your server configuration, because many providers block SMTP by default as a spam prevention measure. - Upgrading your server may have activated IPv6 that you weren't using before. If,  rather than a host based firewall of in addition you had active security groups / firewall rules in your providers infrastructure  controlling and allowing IPv4 egress traffic, those may not have been set up voor IPv6.

As it turns out, the fresh install request of the OS to the hosting company did trigger the port blocking on their infrastructure for reasons unexplained yet (and probably ever). Contacting support got me up and running again (but without RCA or the smallest explanation). Thanks for the comment though.
